# Julia: Make Dataframe from iterator output

Tags: iterator, julia

I am attempting to create a data frame in Julia with two columns, x and y, representing the cartesian product of x values and y values. I think in summary this could be described as using iterator output, a 2D array of tuples, as the argument for DataFrame.

Here's code for obtaining an array of the product tuples (Julia 1.4.2):

```
x = [0:0.1:2;]
y = [0:1.5:30;]
product = collect(Iterators.product(x, y))
```

I want something like this:

```
    x         y 
    Float64  Float64    
1   0.0      0.0    
2   0.1      1.5    
3   0.2      3.0    
4   0.3      4.5    
5   0.4      6.0    
6   0.5      7.5
```

Many thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cartesian product is a set of ordered tuples, so in fact `Iterators.product` returns in such case matrix iterator over tuples, i.e. calling `collect` on `Iterators.product(x,y)` will return `Matrix{Tuple{Float64,Float64}}`

But DataFrame constructor can eat iterator as an argument and return desired result

```
x = 0:0.1:2
y = 0:1.5:30
product = Iterators.product(x, y)
df = DataFrame(product)
rename!(df, [:x, :y])
```

Note that you cannot specify names of df in constructor like `DataFrame(product, [:x, :y])` because there's no such method

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. I especially liked the "eat iterator".

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is even easier. Just write:

```
julia> rename!(DataFrame(vec(product)), [:x, :y])
441×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ x       │ y       │
│     │ Float64 │ Float64 │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │
│ 2   │ 0.1     │ 0.0     │
⋮
│ 439 │ 1.8     │ 30.0    │
│ 440 │ 1.9     │ 30.0    │
│ 441 │ 2.0     │ 30.0    │
```

Another nice pattern for two columns is:

```
julia> flatten(DataFrame(x=x, y=Ref(y)), :y)
441×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ x       │ y       │
│     │ Float64 │ Float64 │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │
│ 2   │ 0.0     │ 1.5     │
⋮
│ 439 │ 2.0     │ 27.0    │
│ 440 │ 2.0     │ 28.5    │
│ 441 │ 2.0     │ 30.0    │
```

If you use `Iterators.product` without materializing it first it is a bit faster, and materializing `Iterators.product` is fastest (but uses a bit more memory):

```
julia> @benchmark rename!(DataFrame(Iterators.product($x, $y)), [:x, :y])
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  10.98 KiB
  allocs estimate:  56
  --------------
  minimum time:     9.400 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      10.000 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        13.129 μs (8.31% GC)
  maximum time:     5.644 ms (99.56% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     1

julia> @benchmark flatten(DataFrame(x=$x, y=Ref($y)), :y)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  17.72 KiB
  allocs estimate:  80
  --------------
  minimum time:     10.299 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      11.300 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        14.268 μs (7.56% GC)
  maximum time:     5.400 ms (99.58% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     1

julia> @benchmark rename!(DataFrame(vec(collect(Iterators.product($x, $y)))), [:x, :y])
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  18.03 KiB
  allocs estimate:  58
  --------------
  minimum time:     6.600 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      7.160 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        9.286 μs (11.73% GC)
  maximum time:     1.104 ms (98.91% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Range`s just directly in the `DataFrame` constructor:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(x=0:0.1:2, y=0:1.5:30)
21×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ x       │ y       │
│     │ Float64 │ Float64 │
├─────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.0     │ 0.0     │
│ 2   │ 0.1     │ 1.5     │
│ 3   │ 0.2     │ 3.0     │
│ 4   │ 0.3     │ 4.5     │
│ 5   │ 0.4     │ 6.0     │
│ 6   │ 0.5     │ 7.5     │
⋮
│ 20  │ 1.9     │ 28.5    │
│ 21  │ 2.0     │ 30.0    │
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't give me all the combinations of x and y and I'm expecting 441 rows, not 21.

Comment: Sorry, I looked at your example output where values were matched in corresponding pairs and I thought that this is what you want - in that case use the answer by Bogumil, nothing to add here.